# How to test bootloader

Tags: operating-system

I have a hello world bootloader code in assembly written (I'm sure I coded it right). I have the .bin file with me and .exe also.

I want to test it now with a USB, how do I do it? Everything I googled out and found on the topic pretty much didn't work out.

I have tried the way with "Disk Explorer NTFS 3.66". I have also tried the mkbt way. Both of them though mentioned highly in blogs/forums/etc don't seem to work for some reason.

Disk Explorer is not letting me paste from file onto the bootsector.

Any ideas/help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. I tried on the virtual machine but didn't work. ( the procedure told by the Disk Explorer NTFS for VM ) Like tell me the steps to make the USB bootable with my bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

I am 99.9% sure that you won't be able to use bootloader with USB. Because, bootloader is initialized first then it loads the Operating System, which loads USB drivers. It can work if you can trick your machine to look for USB as a primary booting device (I was using a P4 with XP and couldn't get my system to do it). The thing that worked for me was a Floopy Drive, it was back in 2006 !

You can use a Virtual Machine as suggested by Federico, and emulate the USB drive as a booting device, that's the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link given below . I think it will help you to make bootloader as "Hello World" in your usb .

http://pcguide4you.blogspot.in/2011/09/designing-simple-hello-world-bootloader.html